# How to interchange the values in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists. I need to interchange the values inside each one.

For example: `['a', 12]` to `[12, 'a']`

Input:

```py
x = [['a', 12],
     ['b', 14],
     ['c', 22],
     ['d', 29],
     ['e', 29],
     ['f', 29],
     ['g', 29],
     ['h', 30],
     ['i', 2],
     ['j', 8]]
```

My expected output:

```py
y = [[12, 'a'],
     [14, 'b'],
     [22, 'c'],
     [29, 'd'],
     [29, 'e'],
     [29, 'f'],
     [29, 'g'],
     [30, 'h'],
     [2, 'i'],
     [8, 'j']]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[i[::-1] for i in list_change]
```

Comment: Clean, simple and pythonic. Take my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```py
list_change = [['a', 12],['b', 14],['c', 22],['d', 29]]
new_list_change = [[sublist[1], sublist[0]] for sublist in list_change]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [['a', 12], ['b', 14], ['c', 22], ['d', 29]]
print([[item[1], item[0]] for item in lst])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[num, let] for let, num in list_change]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following solution the lists are not reconstructed. The data are changed "in place". This may be wanted or unwanted if any other variable is pointing to one of the small lists in the list.

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    a, b = mylist[i]
    mylist[i][:] = b, a
```

If you want to leave everything in place, but generate a new list with swapped elements, use r.ook's answer or—if you think that list comprehension is hard to read—this:

```
newlist = []
for a, b in oldlist:
    newlist.append([b, a])
```