# How to swap the positions of two-dimensional lists?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I want to change position `[85', pass']` to be `['pass', 85]`.

And here is my code:

```
gradebook= [
  ["physics",  98],  
  ["calculus", 97],  
  ["poetry",   85],  
  ["history",  88]  
]
print(gradebook)

gradebook.append(["computer science", 100])
print(gradebook)
gradebook.append(["visual art", 93])
print(gradebook)

# Mengubah nilai 2D list
gradebook[-1][-1]= 98 # menambahkan 5 nilai dari 93 menjadi 98
print(gradebook)

gradebook[2].remove("poetry")# Menghapus poetry dan menggantikannya dengan pass
print(gradebook)
gradebook[2].append("pass")
print(gradebook)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interchange the values in a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962018/how-to-interchange-the-values-in-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @GinoMempin That's about reversing *all* inner lists, though. This question is just about one.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a list comprehension here:

```py
gradebook= [
  ["physics",  98],  
  ["calculus", 97],  
  ["poetry",   85],  
  ["history",  88]  
]
output = [[x[1], x[0]] for x in gradebook]
print(output)
# [[98, 'physics'], [97, 'calculus'], [85, 'poetry'], [88, 'history']]
```

Comment: You're flipping *all* entries, not just the bad one.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [[score, name] for [name, score] in gradebook]
[[98, 'physics'], [97, 'calculus'], [85, 'poetry'], [88, 'history']]
```

Comment: You're flipping *all* entries, not just the bad one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cool method to reverse the order of all items inside a list, in the case of [85,’pass’]:

```
item = gradebook[2]
gradebook[2] = item[::-1]
# gradebook[2] is now = [‘pass’,85]
```

What this basically does when you put in [::-1] is reverse the order of all items in the list.

When you put [] after a list, you can put in more than just the wanted index position for an item, you can call for items in a certain range and a step-size. Step size is like an interval for the list items, for example:

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(lis[0:5:2])
# outputs 1, 3, 5
```

Skipped over every other number (step-size 2) in the range of index positions 0 to 5. So what python does when it reads [::-1] is first: the “::” is default for every item in the list, and second: -1 is our step-size, in this case python would return every item in the list in reversed order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Better: `gradebook[2].reverse()`. Even better: not creating the wrong order in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```
gradebook[2]=[gradebook[2][1],gradebook[2][0]
print(gradebook)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCFR.jpg)

Comment: **[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking or answer a question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)